# Did Neil Armstrong really say "Good Luck Mr. Gorsky" on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, apollo-program, lunar-landing, myth-busting

I have heard, that upon standing on the moon, Neil Armstrong at some point said *"Good luck Mr. Gorsky"*.

The story being that while a child, playing baseball, through an open window he heard Mrs. Gorsky yell at her husband: *"Oral sex, you want oral sex? When the kid next door walks on the Moon!"*

Is that just made up, or real?

Comment: Relevant: [this snopes.com page](http://www.snopes.com/quotes/mrgorsky.asp). It's false.

Comment: @DavidHammen Bummer.  Great joke though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a cute story, an urban legend, but that's all it is. According to [NASA HQ Apollo 11 Lunar Surface Journal](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.step.html) that includes full transcript and [MP3 audio clip](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11a1091545-1101226.mp3) (52 MB) of all the conversations between Apollo 11 astronauts and mission control, as a note near the beginning of the page, there it stands:

> During November 1995, a clever (and slightly risqué) story was widely
>   circulated on the Internet concerning a statement Neil is supposed to
>   have made during the Apollo 11 EVA. At the suggestion of several
>   readers, let me state that Neil never said "Good luck, Mr. Gorsky" at
>   any time during the mission. Indeed, on November 28, 1995, Neil wrote
>   for the ALSJ, "I understand that the joke is a year old. I first heard
>   it in California delivered by (comedian) Buddy Hackett".

So there we have it. It's fiction.

Comment: While I personally believe that in this case, I think there are likely recordings (or part of recordings) which are never published on various reasons (national security, grace for dead astronauts, banal "dirty" things like stool). NASA published even so much more as concurrent space agencies, but logic dictates that not even they should publish everything, ever.